# multiple font awesome icons as rails link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I have the following font-awesome line that is a clickable link

```
%p.add_stuff= link_to(content_tag(:i, nil, class: "fa fa-plus"), new_journey_trip_path(@journey))
```

In addition to fa-plus, I'd like to add another font-awesome plus icon (so it appears something like + + ). How do I achieve this?

I've tried calling fa-plus two times, as well as making two content_tag, but neither seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with link_to, you can nest the contents

```
%p.add_stuff
  = link_to new(journey_trip_path(@journey)) do
    = content_tag(:i, nil, class: "fa fa-plus")
    = content_tag(:i, nil, class: "fa fa-plus")
```

or

```
%p.add_stuff
   = link_to new(journey_trip_path(@journey)) do
     %i.fa.fa-plus
     %i.fa.fa-plus
```

or, you may have the `fa_icon` method available...

```
%p.add_stuff
  = link_to new(journey_trip_path(@journey)) do
    = fa_icon('plus')
    = fa_icon('plus')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
%p.add_stuff= link_to(new_journey_trip_path(@journey)) do
  %i.fa.fa-plus
  %i.fa.fa-plus
```

You can also remove whitespace if needed:

```
%p.add_stuff= link_to(new_journey_trip_path(@journey)) do
  %i.fa.fa-plus>
  %i.fa.fa-plus>
```