# Rails - using font-awesome icons

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, fontawesome-4.4.0

I have a rails 4 app and am trying to use the font awesome icons in it (for social media login links).

I have:

```
 /* application.css.css:
 *= require_framework_and_overrides.css.scss
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

/* framework_and_overrides.css.css: */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

In my gemfile:

```
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
```

I am also using bootstrap sass.

In my view, I try:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(icon('facebook', class: 'facebookauth')) %>
```

It renders "<>>" with nothing in between.

I have also tried:

```
<%= link_to content_tag icon('facebook', class: 'facebookauth') %>
```

I get the same error.

When I try:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(fa_icon('facebook', class: 'facebookauth')) %>
<%= link_to content_tag fa_icon('facebook', class: 'facebookauth') %>
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `fa_icon' for
```

Does anyone know how to use font-awesome in Rails?

A new attempt:

```
                        <%= link_to  icon('google', id: 'googleauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>

                        <%= link_to icon('linkedin', id: 'linkedinauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:linkedin) %>

                        <%= link_to icon('twitter', id: 'twitterauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>
                    <% end %>
```

This works fine to make the links, but I'm trying to put styling on the icons.

I have defined a css div called :facebookauth.

When I change the above, to:

```
<%= link_to icon('facebook', id: 'facebookauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

Or try:

```
<%= link_to icon('facebook', class: 'facebookauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

The links disappear.  I want to make the size bigger and use my color styles. How can I put CSS on these links?

Comment: why do you have `gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'` in your application.scss? or is this just here?

Comment: Hi, that's in my gem file

Comment: Hi. Old question but... `icon("edit fa-lg", class: 'zero')` gives me the following markup: `<i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg zero"></i>`. I guess there was something wrong with 'facebookauth' (id or class) in your css definition like "display: none".

Answer (score 5):

The helper seems to just populate the *content* of the `content_tag` - you still need to provide an element.

[From the docs](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#helpers):

```
content_tag(:li, fa_icon('facebook', class: 'facebookauth'))
```

If you wanted to use the icon on its own, you'd be able to call `fa_icon` individually:

```
fa_icon "camera-retro"
# => <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

--

> how to use the gem as it is intended

All the "web font" gems basically do the following:

1. Create a "web font" of many icons
2. Create a CSS file with classes, each class using a `:before` tag with `content:` of the web font

Each time you call one of the elements of the font (with `class`), you're really just prepending a `:before` with the appropriate font reference.

Therefore, in order to do this, you need a valid HTML element. The `fa_icon` helper seems to create a `<i>` tag -- `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>`. If you want to use it with `content_tag`, you need to therefore provide another element for Rails to wrap the content in.

--

**Update**

Make sure it works like this:

```
<%= link_to fa_icon("facebook", text: "Facebook", class: "facebookauth"), your_path %>
```

We recently used the gem in a project and here's the result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Rich, I'm afraid this is all far too advanced for me. I don't understand any of it. I do want the icon on its own, as a link. That's why I set it out in the way I attempted. No idea what any of this advice means - I'm sure it's sensible to others who might have more understanding of the concepts than I have myself. Thanks anyway but I have no idea where to start in trying to understand this.

Comment: @rich-peck 's answer is correct. to put it more explicitly, use the following code:  `<%= link_to your_route_here do
    = content_tag(:i, fa_icon('facebook', class: 'facebookauth')) %>`. see this stackoverflow answer for more examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326684/multiple-font-awesome-icons-as-rails-link

Comment: @user2860931 you should start by copying the top piece of code I wrote and putting it into your app.

Comment: Thanks, I did try. It gives this error: undefined method `fa_icon' for #<#<Class:0x007ff0ab77ab20>:0x007ff0b1f4c3e8>

Comment: This means you've likely not installed the gem - are you sure it's in your gemfile?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure its included. I can use i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x and it works, but im trying to understand how to use it in rails as shown in the gem docs

Comment: Try changing `font-awesome-sass` to `font-awesome-rails` in your `Gemfile` and rebundling ;)

Comment: No thanks Rich, I'm trying to learn how to use the gem I have installed.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

Pure HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-social btn-github" href="<%= content_tag_url %>">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
</a>
```

Comment: Hi Eleazar, I'd like to try and learn how to use the gem as it is intended. This looks like it might be some sort of override. Not sure what all the styles and formatting are for. Thanks anyway but I think this probably isn't for me.

Comment: Alright, it was just a way to do it using HTML.  Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Add
     `include FontAwesome::Rails::IconHelper` to `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

Comment: I tried this, but get this error: Routing Error
uninitialized constant FontAwesome::Rails

Comment: You added gem "font-awesome-rails" and then if you're using a server like pow did you restart the server?

Comment: What version of font-awesome-rails are you using? font-awesome-rails-3.2.1.3?